# Listening for data via a publicly available URL

Tags: java, http

I'd greatly appreciate some help on this question. 
So, I have a device that is going to push some data in XML format using the http protocol. I give the device a URL and it pushes data to my program. I apologize for being vague but I am curious as to how to start?
I want to implement the server side of this equation, the device being the client!

Comment: what is the device? Blackberry?

Comment: Without more imnformation, you could implement a jersey xml based REST web service and just use http PUT method over the net.

Comment: @Vikdor - No. It's not a blackberry. The device is already set up to send data over HTTP. I am interested in receiving end of data.

Comment: @KaiMattern- Thanks for your comment. I'm sorry I was not clear earlier. I am interested in the receiving end of the equation. The device is set up to send data. I just have to make something to receive the data.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approach, here is a leak of info a bit and confused desire.

XML aren't optimized for mobile communication, use JSON, because has less overhead.

If the device want to send data to server, than I like to use HTTP POST and implement a something on server side to receive it, aka web service, or just a java servlet , or a simple php file...

If the server want to send something to device, than the server should use Push notification, but the payload isn't there ( the xml) , just a notification and the device will pull the xml from server, for eg via HTTP GET.

There are many other cases and imlementations: RMI, SOAP, ...sockets,... alot

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I apologize for not being clear enough in my question. The device is already set up to send data over HTTP. I am interested in the receiving side of the equation. Do you have any ideas on this?

Comment: can't understand how do you want to receive. Do you want to install a web server to your device and let able your desktop application to send data to device without needing the device initialize the request? Usually the device initialize the request, even with a HTTP POST you will get a response from server

Comment: Okay. Lemme try and be more specific. So I have a device that I configure to push data to me periodically. It sends data over HTTP. I want to be able to listen and grab that data. In order for the device to push data I have to give it a URL. So what I am saying is I need to have something running at that URL that I give to the device that grabs the data that the device pushes periodically. Hopefully that sounds better?